# How do I use phpoidc?

Tags: codeigniter, authentication, openid, google-openid, openid-connect

I hope I am not being to dense but I don't know how to use phpoidc. I have downloaded phpoidc from https://bitbucket.org/PEOFIAMP/phpoidc. I have followed the instructions in the INSTALL file. Now that it it supposedly installed, how do I use it? There does not seem to be any documentation on this.

I just want to set up simple user authentication on my site. I am running CodeIgniter 3.0 rc. I primarily want to allow login with google accounts.

Comment: Did you have success using openid-connect? I am curious, I want to add google, twitter and facebook login and registration to a site. It is hard stuff, since twitter and facebook use completely different mechanisms. Did you find a good lib?

Comment: Is there any specific reason you want to run your own OpenID server instead of using a social sign-in library like HybridAuth, which supports Google, Facebook and lots of other logins?

Comment: For what it's worth, you're a _Relying Party_ in this situation, so you'll want to take a look at [`phpRp/INSTALL`](https://bitbucket.org/PEOFIAMP/phpoidc/src/default/phpRp/INSTALL) for what "instructions" exist (I, too, wish there were more documentation on this product...)

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about the OP side or RP side? 
OP side should be quite self-explanatory as it is a stand alone thing. 
RP side needs integration to your application. 
The phpRp is just a sample implementation that uses these libraries. 
What it does is to create an OpenID Connect request and process the call back to see validate the response. Then, typically, an application needs to associate the iss and sub in the ID Token to a local account: you need a mapping table for it. Once you are done with that, create a session and off you go.

Comment: Just to clarify: OP = OpenID Provider, RP = Relying Party. I think it is obvious from the question that s/he wants to use Google as identity provider, so s/he is talking about the RP side.

Comment: `RP side needs integration to your application` - this isn't an answer to the question. I share OP's struggle.